# Formula to return a date in a correspondng column title when specifc text is found in excel

Tags: excel, indexing, vlookup

Hi I am keen to understand the formula I need to return a date in the title of the column where it finds a text ref in a series of rows

[image: excel extract picture]

I have a sheet I want to find a start date by searching a row for the letter `a` and then return the corresponding date in the column title that the letter `a` was found.  I want to similarly do the same for the finsih date, but using the letter `b`.  Vlookups and indexing all seem to look for values in sheets and not the titles, any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=index(c$1:g$1, 1, match("a", c2:g2, 0))
=index(c$1:g$1, 1, match("b", c2:g2, 0))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, very helpful and worked a treat.  Best regards Andy